# Search Alt+F2 history in Cinnamon desktop environment

Tags: linux-mint, command-history, search, cinnamon

I wonder if there's some way to search the Alt+F2 "runner" history most preferably within the dialog itself. I know that in Cinnamon the values are available in `dconf-editor` under `org.cinnamon command-history` but I'm not sure how to take advantage of this knowledge

Currently on Linux Mint 15 if that matters.

**EDIT:**

To be clear, I know that I can cycle through history with Up and Down arrow. I'm looking for a way to quickly find a command I might have run months ago.

Answer (score 3):

Sorry, but there isn't such feature. The key shema only stores the commands run, without timestamp nor any other feature. You can run `dconf read /org/cinnamon/command-history` to get a list and look at the first entry, but apart of that, there's nothing implemented in place that allows you to do this.

Comment: The dconf command doesn't work on my Cinnamon 2.0.14. `dconf read org.cinnamon command-history` gives an error: `dconf key must begin with a slash` and `dconf read /org/cinnamon command-history` returns nothing (though I have used the feature).

Comment: Corrected, err, I found the problem. Try with the last.

Comment: Cool trick, +1!